# Trying to find the windows group policy keys for use with Ansible

Tags: windows, security, ansible, devops, group-policy

I am trying to update group policy in accordance with the CIS framework for a windows 2019 server. There is a module that can be used called [win_security_policy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_security_policy_module.html). However I cannot find the keys to update and set the values. Is there an easy way to locate or extract them all?

On the ansible webpage it states to run the following to view values

```
SecEdit.exe /export /cfg C:\temp\output.ini
```

However this does not list all of the values and it is not easy to understand which keys relate to values specified in the cis recommendations

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you.
In my case i wanted to modify in secpol.msc : local policies/security options/Network security: LDAP client signing requirements & Domain controller: LDAP server signing requirements.
I search on the web, and I found that gpedit is a GUI of Registry key.
Knowing this, I search on the web with these words: registry key Network security: LDAP client signing requirements.
And I found this link: http://windowsbulletin.com/enable-ldap-signing-in-windows-server/
In this page, I found the defined key in regedit of that i wanted to modify in gepedit.

PS: I'm french, be indulgent with my vocabulary :)

Regards,
Grover DURAN